# Find First Instance of String Inside of An Element and Add a Tag Around It

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, replace

What PHP or jQuery could I write that could automatically find the first instance of a phrase (e.g. "Daily Digest") inside of an element (usually a `<p>` tag) and automatically add a span around the text with a class of my choosing?

In other words, I want the first instance of the phrase "Daily Digest" inside of any element on the page to be highlighted in a red color without the user having to add a span around the text themselves (since the people using the site are code illiterate). If the phrase is used more than once inside of a `div` or other element, I would only like the first instance to be highlighted.

Comment: PHP will not manipulate the existing DOM that way. You'll need to look into Javascript and jQuery. With jQuery, it'll be very simple.

Comment: can you pls show your code?

Comment: you can use [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) or simple [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: @DevlshOne I edited the question to include jQuery. What do yo think?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$content = preg_replace('/'.$word.'/i', '<span class="red">$0</span>', $content);
```

Checkout more on preg_replace.

Code tested. It works.

Comment: $0 replaces all matched pattern, and $1 only first. In this case they are the same, as it has only one pattern.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that won't work, have you tried it? There are no capture groups so `$1` is not available.

Comment: No. For that you will need jquery implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(body).filter(function() {
        return $("p", this).text() == "Daily Digest";
    }).wrapAll("<span class='myClass'></span>");
```

Note - this will find all of the instances of `<p>Daily Digest</p>`, and turn them into `<span class='myClass'><p>Daily Digest</p></span>`. I'll let you work out how to do it on only the first instance within a certain element.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
$testwords= preg_replace('/'.$contents.'/i', '<span class="sample">Sample Content</span>', $testwords);
```

Refer https://www.php.net/preg_replace